# Create dataclass that accepts type like List[int]

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

Is it possible to create a dataclass in Python that accepts a type like `List[int]` does?

What I want to do is pass the type to one of the dataclass fields, e.g.

```py
@dataclass
class PagedResponse[type]:
    data: List[type]
    pages: int
```

Comment: You mean a generic https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics?

Comment: Yes! I was unfamiliar with that term. Do you want to add an answer or shall I?